# Random floating Numbers and compare numbers if it is less than or equal to 0.01

Tags: java, random, comparison, compare, floating

In my homework I suppose to generate 10000 floating Numbers and I have to to compare If the difference between two numbers is less than or equal to 0.01 they are considered equal, then remove the second equal number!

here is what I have done, but not sure about compare, will you help me please? Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      int maxSize = 10000;             // array size
      ArrayIns arr;

      arr = new ArrayIns(maxSize);  // create array

      for(int j=0; j<maxSize; j++){  // fill array with
          Random rnd = new Random();    // random numbers
          float n = 0 + rnd.nextFloat() * (100 - 0);
          arr.insert(n);
       }
```

Comment: Sure.. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Pescis I have to compare my numbers If the difference between two numbers is less than or equal to 0.01 they are considered equal. Thank you!

Comment: So you want to count the total of how many are equal, a max value who are equal, what's the point?

Comment: This is my homework :) to compare if they are equal then remove the second similar number!

Comment: What have you tried? If you have it sorted it's not that hard really, just go through the array and check if the number on index i is within 0.01 of index i+1 (`if Math.abs(arr.get(i+1)-arr.get(i))<0.01`), if so remove the number at index i+1 and keep on checking.

Comment: So do I have to put this code within my sort method? This is my actual question :D

Comment: After it, when it's already sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another for loop to iterate through the array value and check if the difference between the value and the outer value is less than 0.01 in which case don't insert the new value into the array

Comment: should i put it inside my insert method ?

Comment: no. use the insert method inside the new for loop. The for loop should check the said logic and if the difference is > 0.01 then only insert. Else don't insert.